# two-ways binding need PATH or XPATH c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xpath, datagrid, path

I'm trying to bind a Database table to a DataGrid, this is my table I'm trying to bind:

```
public partial class Resultat
{
    public string NomTable { get; set; }
    public string Groupe_D_alerte { get; set; }
    public string NomChamp { get; set; }
    public string TOTMPMRQ { get; set; }
    public string SiModifie { get; set; }
    public string LibelléTOTAvant { get; set; }
    public string LibelléTOTApres { get; set; }
    public string Remarque { get; set; }
}
```

This is the Database containing the table I'm trying to bind:

```
public partial class BDDInterneEntities : DbContext
{
    public BDDInterneEntities()
        : base("name=BDDInterneEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<CapitalisationActuelle> CapitalisationActuelle { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DonneesDUMP> DonneesDUMP { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PMRQTOTMGPS> PMRQTOTMGPS { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Resultat> Resultat { get; set; }
}
```

This is the DataGrid I'm using to recieve the binded datas:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DonneesBrutes" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ResultatCollection}" Margin="10,65,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="PMRQ" Width="*" Binding="{Binding XPath=TOTMPMRQ}" Header="PMRQ"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="LibellePMRQ" Width="*" Binding="{Binding XPath=LibelléTOTApres}" Header="Libellé PMRQ"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Ligne" Width="*" Header="Ligne"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="OTM" Width="*" Header="OTM"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="TOTM" Width="*" Header="TOTM"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="LibelleTOTM" Width="*" Header="Libellé OTM"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="GA" Width="*" Header="GA"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Discipline" Width="*" Header="Discipline"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DisciplineSubstituee" Width="*" Header="Discipline Substituée"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

I'm calling a ViewModel to bind datas, like this:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

With local:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3;assembly="
```

Where ViewModel is the core of the binding:

```
class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private BDDInterneEntities _BDDInterneEntities;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        _BDDInterneEntities = new BDDInterneEntities();
        ResultatCollection = new ObservableCollection<Resultat>(_BDDInterneEntities.Resultat);

    }         
    public ObservableCollection<Resultat> ResultatCollection { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

I have two main problems with this. I have some test datas into Resultat. When I Start, I see the graphic interface with the Datagrid, like this:

Resultat DataGrid: http://uprapide.com/image/831306-capture_9978

As we can see in this image, the DataGrid Binding "knows" I have two lines into my table Resultat but we don't see the Datas.
Another problem arrives if I want to insert datas into any case of the DataGrid. If I try to do this, I have "two-ways binding need PATH or XPATH " error.

Hope I gave enough informations, sounds it is my main problem..

If somebody knows what I did wrong?

EDIT1:

Second problem is solved, I used XPATH and should not.
But the First Problem is still here. I don't see datas into the DataGrid.. Same in the other side, If I write datas into the Interface DataGrid, they're not written into DB.

Comment: try setting `Path=.` in the binding. this would suppress the error but not sure if that may help you to save the data as well.

Comment: I have the same error, sounds not working.

Comment: this approach usually does not solve error when you are binding to properties but to the viewmodel itself. eg `<TextBox Text="{Binding}"/>` will give you the two way binding error where as `<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.}"/>` will not.

Comment: but... I'm using the second solution, the `<DataGrid x:Name="DonneesBrutes" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.ResultatCollection}" ................>` and I still got the error

Comment: Remove your `XPath Binding`s... they are only required for data binding to XML data.

Comment: Okay, I haven't any error now. The datas aren't written into the table, but I can write some informations. I finally can get something like this: http://uprapide.com/image/831364-capture_9979
If i click into an other case than where I wrote "dsq" It'll add another line. Now I only have the first problem, the properties sound be accounted (add new line for example) but datas aren't well binded. In one way, or in the other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is What I had to do, I have finally found what I was looking for:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DonneesBrutes" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ResultatCollection}" Margin="10,65,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="PMRQ" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=TOTMPMRQ}" Header="PMRQ"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="LibellePMRQ" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=LibelléTOTApres}" Header="Libellé PMRQ"></DataGridTextColumn>
```

My error, was using XPATH instead of PATH on the `<DataGridTextColumn>` Then, Using Path=. works as well and sounds to be more interesting for two-way binding.